# Different ways to prove Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: polynomials, roots, big-list

This is just a curosity .I know some proofs of the fact that Every non constant polynomial with complex coefficient has a  complex root via using  Liouville's theorem in Complex Analysis.Proof goes as follows:

Let $p(z)$ be a nonconstant polynomial, and by contradiction suppose it has no zeroes.  Then $f(z) = 1/p(z)$ is an entire function. If P is non constant, $p(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$, and so $f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$ and $f$ is bounded.But,then by Liouville's theorem $p$ is constant,contradiction to our assumption.

I have seen one more proof which uses Field extensions and  Splitting fields. 
I would like to know some more proofs because it's interesting to see that something can be proved in many different ways.
Do you have any other nice proofs?

Comment: Relevant thread on math overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra

Comment: And also the collection on wikipedia's FTA page.